# Convert object array to data table in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ , I have successfully parsed an XML into an object array lv1s as below.

```
var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("build")
           select new
           {
               Number = lv1.Descendants("number"),
               Result = lv1.Descendants("result"),
               Timestamp = lv1.Descendants("timestamp")
           };
```

Wanted to know what is the simplest way to convert this object array into a datatable with columns Number,Result,timestamp?

Comment: Create a new datatable with those columns, then loop through entries in `lv1s` and add rows for each?

Comment: *Why* do you want it in a `DataTable`? Is there a specific reason for that? (`DataTable` is vastly overused)

Comment: I am trying to use SqlBulkCopy . It requires a datatable as parameter. So wanted to check if there is a work around, instead of looping through each item.

Comment: @mhn Try `dataSet.ReadXml`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @SurajSingh . Thanks .. This looks like the simplest method available for my issue. Please make it an answer. Will choose as best answer.

Comment: @mhn Well since your question is marked as duplicate no-one can post any answer on this question.However i'm glad if that link helped.